# Width measurement in CSS

Tags: css, frontend, width, pixel

for a beginner in web development I'm facing a major problem in dealing with Width and other measuring attributes through unclarity of how to deal with Pixels and other measuring units.
When I try to set a specific width for an element I have to go through Trial and Error in order to know what's the appropriate number. So my question is how to know the max allowed width number in order to determine the width I want to set instead of keep trying and wasting time, for example if the full width is 1000px it'll be clear that if I want and element to occupy half of the screen it'll be 500px, but the point is how to know that the full width is equal to 1000px, 2000px or whatever. Like is there any tool or method to know exactly ? or trial is my friend in this case?

Comment: Did you try `width:50%;` ?

Comment: There are several options. I'd recommend looking into [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). Other options is to use % or vw/vh as units. There are also rulers in the developer console that you can enable, if you want to stick with pixels.

Comment: @Cédric yes I have tried but when there is borders , margins and paddings it's different, my goal is to figure out how to know the maximum pixels allowed in order to know how to deal with this instead of keep adding and removing till I reach what I want.

Comment: Your question is kind of all over the place, but you should consider reading up on how the various units work and when and why you use them. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units  Trial and error is how you learn, so that will always be your friend no matter what :) I also like this cheat sheet from GitHub when I'm working: https://gist.github.com/basham/2175a16ab7c60ce8e001 Everyone has their opinion on it but it's worked well for me.

Comment: @Jákup Well I'm still learning HTML and CSS and didn't go to and framework yet , so I'm still using the basic properties and measuring units . So I prefer understanding the basics before going higher .

Comment: You can take one of the tutorial about css measures. for example [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units).

Comment: @AStombaugh Well I have read many posts but I don't know if they mean the same thing and to be honest I don't know if my explanation was clear or not.

Comment: @Dash I mean, your question is pretty vague. You're asking how to know the max allowed width but the max allowed width of what exactly? Are you trying to measure an element on a website or are you trying to build a site? If you're building something why not post a [mre] so we can see what you're doing and maybe tell us what your end goal is?

Comment: @AStombaugh I got you. Let's say we have a block element , so it'll take the full width by default, in this case the full width is the screen width, so how can I know that specific width. Another example would be that I have a <div> element and I want to make it half the full width but I want to use pixels , if I know the full and let's say it's 1000px then i can say width=500px, but if I don't know I'll say 500px and then it won't be the half so I'll have to try 700px and then 900px until i reach the middle , in that case it's a waste of time , I hope this is clearer

Comment: "I want to use pixels" - There's your problem. Stop doing that. You don't get to decide which CSS features to use to complete a task. The task determines which features you need. For your task, percentage units will form some part of the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Alohci You are right , but I have mentioned that I'm still a beginner , so I'm trying to figure out problems with what I know , Thank you.